# Transfer music from iPad's iTunes to MacBook's, devices have different iTunes accounts

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, ipad

My Dad has an iPad with a lot of songs downloaded onto its iTunes library. Is it possible for me to put the songs onto my MacBook?

The iPad uses my Dad's iTunes account and the MacBook mine.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to share iTunes content between multiple Apple IDs is their family sharing plan. My father and I use it to share movies and TV shows with each other. Apple gives instructions for [setting up family sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088). While it is nice to share content, it definitely has drawbacks. The biggest is that there can only be one credit card registered to all accounts under a family plan. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's generally not possible to transfer the synced music from the iPad to your MacBook using conventional (i.e. Apple supplied) means.

You would need to copy over the songs from your Dad's Mac (or where it originated from).

Comment: My dad downloaded the songs from the iTunes store on his iPad.

Comment: Then he needs to download them on your iPad too using his Apple-ID. If you enable family sharing, you can then open up access for you yourself to do that also.

Comment: I'd like them on my MacBook. Does he have to sign in onto that?

Comment: Yes, if he wants to access songs he paid for on iTunes Store, he needs to be logged in to be able to use the account.